# UFT how to get data

Tags: hp-uft

I want to use UFT to get the data between tabindex=3 and tabindex=4. Does anyone know how to do this?  Thanks.

```
<span class=' header-link' tabindex=3>Patrick Conch</span>
<span  class=' header-link'  tabindex=4>Managing Director</span>
```

Comment: Please describe your question, this information might not help.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Please share what you have already tried and ellaborate better your question. Give us something to work with :)

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Sounds to me like you want to extract the content of the `span` tags in the html?  We want to help you, but we need a bit more info...

Comment: Is there anything between  tabindex=3 and tabindex=4 ?

Comment: The expected output would be Patrick Conch and Managing Director.  
<p>
Here is the entire block of code.. 
<p>
<div class=" " >
<div style="right:0px;width:100%;text-align:right">
<a tabindex=2 href="#TopOfPage" id="skipNav">Skip to content</a> 
<span class=' header-link' tabindex=3>Patrick Conch</span>
<span  class=' header-link'  tabindex=4>Managing Director</span>
<a  tabindex=5 class='header-link' href="/spcp2/logout" style="font-size:11px">Logout</a>
</div>
</div>

Comment: Then ```text = Browser.Page.WebElement ("xpath:=//span [@tabindex=3]").GetROProperty ("text")``` should work. Of course update Browser and Page with your values.